# PyCharm: How to run with prompt for params?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, args

I am parsing the command line arguments in my Python code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e', '--epochs', type=int, default=50)
parser.add_argument('-ts', '--train-size', type=int, default=None)
parser.add_argument('-ti', '--title', default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

So everytime I run the Python file I am able to specify title and other things I need. But since PyCharm needs run config to run, I have to manually edit run configs and save everytime I want to run.

**Is there way hack to make this thing pop-up just before I run the experiment?**

[image]

One simple way is to use the terminal from inside and just run the script with args like I do in command prompt, but I lose other configuration like the env vars, Python interpreter, conda environment, etc., when I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-74031](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature (currently planned for the next major release)

Comment: Well ... user can tick `Show this page` option in specific Run/Debug Configuration ... so IDE will show Configuration and user can edit any info before actually executing it. I strongly believe OP wants this rather than some variables in Configuration...

Answer (score 3):

This is possible now because run configuration parameters can include Jetbrains Macros, one of which triggers an input prompt. There are some limitations:

- there is no label for the prompt
- you can add multiple prompts, but since they aren't labelled you would have to remember the order you added the `$Prompt$`s in, since that will be the order they pop up when you run your Run Configuration.

[image: example of adding prompts]

[image: example of running]

Comment: How should parameters be entered in the prompt? using the syntax `--parameter-name parameter_value --another-parameter another_value` does not work for me